# include botan 2 in compilation

Tags: c++, gcc, botan

i try include some botan header in compilation process

```
#include <botan/rng.h>
#include <botan/auto_rng.h>
#include <botan/cipher_mode.h>
#include <botan/hex.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        return 0;
}
```

I found that i need to compile with following command in order to build successfully

```
g++ app.cpp -I/usr/local/include/botan-2
```

i saw some folks execute

```
g++ app.cpp -lbotan-2
```

i tried it out but i get a error

```
'app.cpp:1:10: fatal error: botan/rng.h: No such file or directory
 #include <botan/rng.h>
```

Am i missing anything ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following command:

```
g++ app.cpp -lbotan-2
```

links botan-2 with `app.cpp` but you still need to specify where to find the headers:

```
g++ app.cpp -I/usr/local/include/botan-2 -lbotan-2
```

Under my system, the headers for botan-2 are in `/usr/include/botan-2`. So, make sure you are giving the right path.